# printing a returned array java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, printing

hello this is my first post. 
I'm sorry if not asking on the correct section but i am having trouble with this homework i got. im supposed to write a single method that returns 5 computations in a single dimensional array.
 Once i try to print it, it prints the value of 0.0 for every element of the array. i believe that i might be failing to input the values i want into the returned array but im not sure. does anyone know how to solve this?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers: ");
        double [] numbers = new double[5];
        double [] answers = calculations(numbers);

        for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.println("the maximum of the five numbers is: " + answers[0]);
        System.out.println("the minimum of the five numbers is: " + answers[1]);
        System.out.println("the average of the five numbers is: " + answers[2]);
        System.out.println("the standard deviation of the five numbers is: " + answers[3]);
        System.out.println("the sum of the five numbers is: " + answers[4]);

    }

    public static double[] calculations(double []numbers){
        double[] answers = new double[5];
        double max = numbers[1];
        double min = numbers[1];
        double sum = 0;

        //find max
        for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            if (numbers[i] > max) max = numbers[i];  
        }
        answers[0] = max;

        //find min
        for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            if (numbers[i] < min) min = numbers[i];  
        }
        min = answers[1];

        //find sum
        for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            sum = numbers[i] + sum;
            }
         answers[4] = sum;

        //find average
        double average = (sum / numbers.length);
         answers[2] = average;

        //find standard dev

        double sumOfSquared = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            sumOfSquared = sumOfSquared + Math.pow((numbers[i] - average),2);
        }
        double standarDev = Math.pow((sumOfSquared/numbers.length), .5);
         answers[3] = standarDev;

        return answers;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing your calculations after your get the input

```
    double [] answers = calculations(numbers);

    for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
        numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
```

to

```
    for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
        numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }

    double [] answers = calculations(numbers);
```

Comment: thank you so much!! I'm such a newbie just couldn't figure that out for such a long time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Except for what user puj mentioned above, change this part of "find-min":

```
min = answers[1];
```

to

```
answers[1] = min;
```

Or else you will always get 0.0 as a minimum value.

Comment: Thank you! i had not noticed that